# Ubuntu dual boot installation in Acer Aspire boots straight to windows 10, no EFI file found

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, acer

I installed ubuntu 20.04 in a new Acer Aspire laptop. After installation, I restarted the computer which boots straight to windows. I have seen several solutions that require restarting the computer, going into BIOS, setting a supervisor password and then selecting an EFI file as trusted ([example of solution](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/605012/how-to-dual-boot-windows-ubuntu-acer-aspire-e15-e5-575g-5622)), but during that step I'm supposed to select "ubuntu" which is not listed. I'm stumped. What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: I thought it said unknown and you are to change it to whatever you want or just "ubuntu".  You may have both grubx64.efi and shimx64.efi. Both work if UEFI Secure boot is off when booting, only shimx64.efi will work with UEFI Secure boot on, if you also installed all the signed kernels & drivers. (or booted installer in Secure Boot mode). If you need proprietary drivers, generally easier to have Secure Boot off.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your Acer forum link there is missing EFI partition. Have you created it or not? If not then reinstall Ubuntu again using manual partition. Use this video as guide to create partition https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lG0jWnBZhY0 Once you finish then you have able to choose trusted boot file.